# android how to get date and time for now moment

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

i have app that needs to get date and time for now moment, anyone can help thank you

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

maybe from Calender object?

Comment: [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html). Documentation is your friend.

Comment: `new java.util.Date()` also give you the answer

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` is also a number that represents "now". What kind of date and time do you need?

Comment: thank i'm just biggner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simple search on any search engine could have helped you. Eg:

```
String date = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-"+ c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+ "-"+ c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) ;
String time = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+ ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Comment: thank you feel good just some Rpoints